# Simplified way of installing a com dll created in C# - Need expert suggestion

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

**The requirement**
Call C# function from classic ASP.

**The solution**

After hours of research i was able to call a c# function from classic asp. I feel i have done so many steps (below). Not sure if this is the right way. Looking for expert suggestion.

Development Machine: VS 2010
Production Server: Windows 2008 with Framework 4 installed

### Steps followed to create com dll in C# (development machine)

1. Create a class library project
2. Pasted the following code

   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

   namespace cominter
   {
       [Guid("EAA4976A-45C3-4BC5-BC0B-E474F4C3C83F")]
       public interface ComClass1Interface
       {
           string test();

   ```
   }



   [Guid("0D53A3E8-E51A-49C7-944E-E72A2064F938"),
       ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
   [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
   public class ComClass1 : ComClass1Interface
   {
       public string test()
       {
           return "vivek";
       }

   }
   ```

   }
3. in the properties-> build, check Register for COM Interop
4. in the properties-> Signing, check sign the assembly. created a key file
5. built the solution
6. used regasm /regfile to create regfile

### Steps followed in Server 2008 (production) to install the dll

1. Copied gacutil.exe and gacutil.exe.config from development machine C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\ to the server C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
2. ran the registry file generated from the development machine

Is there a better way? I'm also not sure if all the steps above are required. Any expert suggestion would be great.

**Questions**

1. what is the use of GUID above teh class name and the inter face name. is it really required? i just copied this from msdn. if it is required, should i create my own id or leave it. is there a tool to create this guid
2. is interface required. can it work without interface?
3. is creating key necessary. When i installed this dll in production, I didn't copy the key file.
4. what are the files to be copied. i copied dll and tlb file and ran the gacutil
5. is there a better way of installing this com dll
6. i ran the registry script. is this required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on this topic, but I have done something similar a few times. I my cases it has been .Net assemblies used by VB6 applications not websites. So here are my experiences on your questions.

1. I have never used a GUID on my projects, so it is not required. (There is a tool in the .NET SDK to create GUIDs)
2. As far as I know an interface is required.
3. The signing of your assembly is necessary, you cannot install/register your dll if it is not signed. You don't copy the keyfile, it is only used when compiling your project.
4. You only need your dll and tlb file. If you are referencing any other libraries you are using, you need them as well.
5. On my projects I have used an setup project from visual studio to register my VB6 app and my .Net library, that have worked fine for me when distributing the application.
6. As far as I know, it is not required.